# Fixed Point (Value equal to index) in a given array using Linear Search - Logic question

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linear-search

Can someone provide an explanation why using this method below returns only the first matching value within the array? For example if My array element is 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. It will return 0, instead of 4. Every value within the array matches to its index 4, should using the for loop return 4 after the last iteration is completed?

```
static int linearSearch(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        int i; 
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            if(arr[i] == i) 
                return i; 
        } 
        
        /* If no fixed point present  
           then return -1 */
        return -1; 
    } 
    //main function
```

Comment: What do you mean by fixed point here? How are you calling this method? You are comparing the index with the array element, so when they match it will return that index. With the example given by you, for `i = 0` the comparison `arr[0] == 0` will be true and it will return `i` i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because in your `if` you immediately call `return`, and your method is supposed to return a single `int`. If you want to collect all fixed points, you can modify your method like this:

```
static List<Integer> linearSearch(int arr[], int n)
{
    List<Integer> fixedPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == i)
            fixedPoints.add(i);
    }

    return fixedPoints;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, What if I want to just return the last matching value within the array?

Comment: Then the same code as yours, just change loop direction: `for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 2):

This will return 4 as it has an updated index for each i matching to its value in an array.

```
static int linearSearch(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        int i,index = -1; 
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            if(arr[i] == i) 
                index = i; 
        } 
        
        /* If no fixed point present  
           then return -1 */
        return index; 
    } 
    //main function
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Can someone provide an explanation why using this method below
> returns only the first matching value within the array?

A method returns to the code that invoked it when reaches a return statement.

From [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html):

> **Returning a Value from a Method**
>
> A method returns to the code that invoked it when it
>
> - completes all the statements in the method,
> - reaches a return statement, or
> - throws an exception,
>
> whichever occurs first.

The statement `if(arr[i] == i)`  returns true at the first step of the `for` loop:

```
i=0
arr[0]=0
```

Then the line `return i;` executed.

> Q: Every value within the array matches to its index 4, should using
> the for loop return 4 after the last iteration is completed?

In this condition the last iteration is the first iteration of the `for` loop. It runs only for `i=0`. The value of `i` never reaches to 4.